# Error received while Copying a table between different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My server name is `Server\SQL2008`. I want to copy a table from another server into my server.

I am using this code:

```
insert into SERVER\SQL2008.DBTiger.dbo.Sample_TBL 
   select * 
   from SERVER.DBTiger.dbo.Sample_TBL
```

SQL Server doesn't recognize `\` and I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `[SERVER].[SQL2008].[DBTiger].[dbo].[Sample_TBL]` ?

Comment: You need to enclose the server name in square brackets - `[SERVER\SQL2008.DBTiger].DBTiger.dbo.Sample_TBL`

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved in this approach but Now I have another problem:
Could not find server 'SERVER\SQL2008' in sys.servers.
But I am seeing this server in my object explorer in Sql Server.

Comment: @m.kh: For that you need to make **Linked server**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the server you are trying to refer is Linked server. Below link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff772782.aspx) MSDN page describes way to create linked server. Once server is linked, you can access it as `[SERVER\SQL2008.DBTiger].DBTiger.dbo.Sample_TBL`.